# Tensorboard is not populating graph on windows

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard, tensorflow-xla

I have written simple python program to multiply two values and expected to populate the tensorboard graph.

I am using Windows - CPU machine.

Then after executing my program it generated required graph event file in the log directory path with the name `events.out.tfevents.1504266616.L7`

I use the below command to start tensorboard:

```
tensorboard --logdir C:\\Users\\SIMBU\\python_pgm\\TensorFlow\\graph --host 127.0.0.1 --port 5626
```

However, there is no graph under `http://127.0.0.1:5626/#graphs`.

What i have did wrong?

Comment: Have you tried forward slashes? C:/Users/SIMBU/python_pgm/TensorFlow/graph

Comment: @JonasAdler - Awesome Buddy! It worked :)

Comment: Also make sure you close the file writer object too.

Comment: @jdehesa sure thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tensorboard requires that you use linux style paths with forward slashes, e.g.

```
tensorboard --logdir C:/Users/SIMBU/python_pgm/TensorFlow/graph
```